# Twitter email notifications but no new followers

Tags: twitter

I can't figure out Twitter's follower statistics. I get emails from Twitter that somebody has started following me but when I go to my profile, the number is same, that is 210 and sometimes it increases by 1, a reason why it is at 210 by now.

Why is it so?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Somebody joins, somebody leaves...

Most probably whoever started following you was a spammer hoping you will look on their profiles and/or follow them. By the time you got to Twitter, somebody else marked them as spammer and they got blocked.

Easy enough to confirm that - if they follow a lot of people but are not at all followed back, they are probably a spammer. You can also click on their name you got in your Twitter email and check who they follow and whether they are even still on the system.

Finally, just make sure those emails are not a *scam* themselves and do go to Twitter. Otherwise, they might be phishing for your Twitter password.